# Android gradle build fails even for new projects

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle

After updating Android Studio (to 3.2.1), Build Tools (28.0.3), SDK, and Gradle (to 5.0) all tries for building an app fail. Even with new projects.
This is the error I get when I run `./gradlew clean` in Android Studio's terminal:

> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.

**However, I am able to download and open all these files and the internet connection has no problem or proxies**

Here is the app Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.ddtapp.acepte"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

And the project's Gradle file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And Gradle Wrapper :

```
#Thu Nov 22 19:38:06 AEDT 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-all.zip
```

And Gradle properties :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

org.gradle.warning.mode=all
```

Comment: Gradle 5.0 seems incompatible with AS 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on macOs and the problem was with a **gradle.properties** file in this path:

```
/Users/__username__/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

It looks like an old misconfiguration that Android Studio used without showing an option pointing to it.

I found the path under **Global Gradle Settings** in Android Studio preferences.

Edit 1:

Now build command works in built-in terminal but the IDE won't sync gradle yet.

Edit 2:

Build button in IDE works as well but still says "gradle sync failed". Tried deleting .gradle folder in user data path above. That didn't work too.

Edit 3:

Deleted both *.gradle* folders in the user data directory and project directory, built the project and used custom gradle distribution (downloaded from the website)

Comment: p.s. Gradle s_ucks

Answer (score 0):

Update below code in your project level build.gradle and sync your project :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**I have added `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }`**

Comment: That didn't work either. I've tried that before.
The _.gradle_ folders fixed that